# Как получить путь к файлу-аттачу в задаче в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, api

Вижу у задачи прикрепленные файлы:
http://joxi.ru/V2VB9eMIdVGv72
Однако при попытке получить путь к файлу:

```
CFile::GetPath(intval(330921));
```

получаю пустоту.

Судя по всему, это не тот id. А как мне тогда использовать это число для получения пути к файлу?

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule("tasks"))
{
    $arr = [];
    $rsTask = CTasks::GetList(
        ["CREATED_DATE" => "DESC"],
        ["REAL_STATUS" => array(CTasks::STATE_NEW, CTasks::STATE_PENDING, CTasks::STATE_IN_PROGRESS, CTasks::STATE_SUPPOSEDLY_COMPLETED)],
        ["UF_*", "*"],
        []
    );
    while($arTask = $rsTask->GetNext()){
        $arr[] = [
            "task" => $arTask["ID"],
            "file" => $arTask["UF_TASK_WEBDAV_FILES"]
        ];
    }
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Результат **CFile::getByID(330921)**:

```
CDBResult Object
(
    [result] => 
    [arResult] => Array
        (
        )

    [arReplacedAliases] => 
    [arResultAdd] => 
    [bNavStart] => 
    [bShowAll] => 
    [NavNum] => 
    [NavPageCount] => 
    [NavPageNomer] => 
    [NavPageSize] => 
    [NavShowAll] => 
    [NavRecordCount] => 
    [bFirstPrintNav] => 1
    [PAGEN] => 
    [SIZEN] => 
    [SESS_SIZEN] => 
    [SESS_ALL] => 
    [SESS_PAGEN] => 
    [add_anchor] => 
    [bPostNavigation] => 
    [bFromArray] => 1
    [bFromLimited] => 
    [sSessInitAdd] => 
    [nPageWindow] => 5
    [nSelectedCount] => 0
    [arGetNextCache] => 
    [bDescPageNumbering] => 
    [arUserFields] => 
    [SqlTraceIndex] => 
    [DB] => 
    [NavRecordCountChangeDisable] => 
    [is_filtered] => 
    [nStartPage] => 0
    [nEndPage] => 0
    [resultObject] => 
)
```

Результат:

```
$taskId = 354059;
$userId = $USER->getId();
$oTask = CTaskItem::getInstance($taskId, $userId);
print_r($oTask->getFiles());
```

возвращает пустой массив

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: каким образом вы получаете то что на скриншоте? Приведите пример кода

Comment: @Taarim привел пример кода

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/tasks/classes/ctaskitem/getfiles.php - попробуйте этот метод, он вернет вам те же самые идентификаторы? и пробовали ли скормить идент функции CFile::getByID() и какой результат?

Comment: @Taarim добавил результаты

Comment: Это же корп портал у вас? И второй вопрос - файлы, пути которых нужно получить, задаче наверное загружены на "диск"?

Comment: Да, это портал корпоративный. Нужно все задачи с прикрепленными файлами перенести на новую версию Битрикс24

Comment: по поводу диска не могу сказать, вот вижу эти файлы в задаче - http://joxi.ru/YmEnBkZfw99V12. Также вышеприведенный код отображает три файла, прикрепленные к этой задаче, судя по всему, эти. А вот как получить ссылку на эти файлы, чтоб перенести автоматом на другой портал, не могу разобраться.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4kBpwhoZZlZ2

Comment: \Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('disk');
$attachedId = 330921;
$path = \Bitrix\Disk\Driver::getInstance()->getUrlManager()->getUrlToActionShowUfFile(330921);
var_dump($path); попробуйте вот так получить

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Bitrix\Disk\Driver' not found

Comment: модуль Disc видимо отсутствует

Comment: вышел из положения путем sql-запроса: "SELECT i.value, f.subdir, f.file_name, f.id FROM b_iblock_element_property as i, b_file as f WHERE i.iblock_property_id = 39 AND i.value = f.id AND i.iblock_element_id = {$file_id}"

Answer (score 1):

Я подозреваю что там id это стоика с префиксом n (n234 например), просто вот документации когда их устанавливают эту самую n к ID файла переклеивают вот ка здесь:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/tasks/classes/ctaskitem/update.php

А обще информации по этой теме очень мало.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Возвращается в этом случае не истинный ИД файла, а некий идентификатор-ссылка на него в коллекции `UserFields`.

Вот как можно получить прикрепленный файл из задачи в Bitrix24, используя возможности Bitrix D7 (а затем ид, путь, ссылку и что угодно).

Попробуйте исполнить этот snippet в "командной строке CLI" админки вашего Bitrix24. Только не забудьте заменить `$taskID` на номер вашей задачи с вложениями:

```
//title: Получить все вложения из задачи
try {
    CModule::IncludeModule("tasks");
    CModule::IncludeModule("disk");
} catch (\Bitrix\Main\SystemException $e) {
    die($e);
}

// Положим, наша заявка с номером 422
$taskID = 422;

// Берем инстанс таска по его ИД с правами Администратора
// (второй аргумент - ид пользователя от имени которого производятся манипуляции)
$insTask = new \Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task(intval($taskID), 0);
$arrTask = $insTask->getData();
$arrAttachmentIDs = $arrTask['UF_TASK_WEBDAV_FILES']->toArray(); // это не обязательно но я перестраховщик

// Теперь попробуем собрать массив, каждый член которого будет иметь имя файла и его содержимое в Base64
// Это так, для примера
$arTaskAttachments = [];

if (!empty($arrAttachmentIDs)) {
    foreach ($arrAttachmentIDs as $attachmentID) {
        $diskDriver = \Bitrix\Disk\Driver::getInstance();
        $objAttachment = $diskDriver->getUserFieldManager()->getAttachedObjectById(intval($attachmentID));
        // Так мы получили объект типа Вложение (Attachment). До самого файла нужно еще добраться.
        $objFile = $objAttachment->getObject();
        // И вот только теперь у нас - файл. Получим его имя и ИД.
        $fileID = $objFile->getFileId();
        $fileName = $objFile->getName();
        $filePath = \CFile::GetPath($fileID);
        $fileB64Contents = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filePath));
        $arTaskAttachments[] = [
            'filename' => $fileName,
            'b64contents' => $fileB64Contents
        ];
    }
}
var_dump($arTaskAttachments);
```